# libvirtError: XML error: expected unicast mac address, found multicast

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm

I'm setting up KVM automation via ansible and I have one VM which keeps giving me this error:

libvirtError: XML error: expected unicast mac address, found multicast '53:54:00:b4:ad:81'

I don't believe this is an ansible problem, as several other VMs work just fine.  I've tried a different host, even changing the MAC used to one that has worked before as well as one that has never been used.  Best I can tell this is NOT a multicast mac address, I'm not sure what the problem is or where to look next.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is the XML I'm using to build the VM - Based on the same template that's building all my other VM's (except for the MAC address, name, etc.).

```xml
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>te01</name>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='1' threads='1'/>
  </cpu>
  <memory unit='GiB'>8</memory>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='writeback' discard='ignore' io='threads'/>
      <source file='/images/te01.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <mac address='53:54:00:b4:ad:81'/>
      <guest dev='ens3'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='br502'/>
      <guest dev='ens5'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <graphics type='vnc' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Best I can tell this is NOT a multicast mac address...

But it really is a multicast address, although not in the sense of an IPv4 multicast to MAC multicast (`01-00-5E-00-00-00` through `01-00-5E-7F-FF-FF`), IPv6 multicast to MAC multicast (`33-33-00-00-00-00` through `33-33-FF-FF-FF-FF`), or any of the predefined IEEE multicast addresses, e.g. STP, LLDP, etc..

There are two flags in the most-significant byte of a MAC address. The least-significant bit of the most-significant byte is the I/G (Individual/Group) flag. Setting this bit means that the address is used as a destination address to a group. The second least-significant bit of the most-significant byte is the U/L (Universal/Local) flag. Setting this bit means that the MAC address was locally created; BIAs (Burned-in-Addresses) have the U/L bit clear.

Any MAC address with the I/G bit set is a multicast address, with a special case for the broadcast MAC address (`ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff`). That means that any odd number in the most-significant byte of the MAC address is a multicast address.

Multicast addresses can only be destination addresses, not an address assigned to an interface.

Your MAC address, `53:54:00:b4:ad:81`, has both the I/G bit set, meaning that it is a multicast (destination group) address, and the U/L bit set, meaning that it is a locally defined MAC address.

The most-significant byte is 0x53 (`01010011`), so both flags are set.

```
0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1
                        ^   ^
                        |   |
                       U/L I/G
```

Any MAC addresses you create, exclusive of any OUI you own, are supposed to have the U/L bit set to show that you have created them, and that they will not step on an OUI owned by a different company (unfortunately, a lot of people that make up their own MAC addresses do not do this, but there really isn't any way to enforce it). Interface addresses must have the I/G bit clear to prevent them from being multicast (group destination) addresses.

---

People often ask why the flags are the two least-significant bits of the most-significant byte. That is because of the order bits, bytes, and frame fields are sent on ethernet. The least-significant bit of a byte is sent first, the most-significant byte of a frame is sent first, and the first field of a frame is the destination address. Also, remember that ethernet was originally on a shared medium (the way Wi-Fi is now), so all hosts on the LAN saw all frames. The first bit received at a host tells a host seeing the frame if the destination address is an individual or group address.

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly the explanation I needed.   Turns out all the other mac addresses I'm using start with 52, not 53 and I hadn't noticed.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and writing this answer! +karma :)

Answer (score 1):

The TL;DR of Ron Maupin's answer is:

For maximum compatibility, when creating your own MAC address, the second digit in the first byte must be either a 2, 6, A or E.

When converted to binary they represent 00:10, 01:10, 10:10 and 11:10.

This results in the U/L bit being set to "Locally Created" and the I/G bit being unset signaling that it's not a group address.