# Algorithm for mac address assignment with enc28j60

Tags: networking, embedded, stm32

I recently found out that some ethernet modules like `enc28j60` provide api for mac address assignment. I was surprised because I thought the manufactor will assign this address in unique way. So, what is the way to solve this problem? I know, that in the case of private local networks manual assignment will solve this problem (probability of collision is small). But it is interesting for me about other ways to cope with it. Theoretically I can suppose some algorithms:

1. Device can assign part of mac address in random way after reset. Reseting can be automatic.
2. There is server, which supports some connection with `enc28j60`. It scans network and will assign unique mac address.

`Mentioned above methods have drawbacks if sometime device with the same mac address will be appeared`

3. Just to buy some range of mac addresses for personal use

Comment: Number 4. Use the U/L flag as you should in order to prevent collisions with vendor-assigned addresses on other hosts. [See [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809679/3745413) about that.

Comment: @RonMaupin I knew about this flag, but it does not exclude potential situation when there is the same mac adress (where u\l flag is set)

Comment: It is the equivalent of your number 3. You control what is or is not used on the network.