# Ethernet frame, source address

Tags: networking, ethernet

> As Source Address is always an individual address (Unicast), the least
> significant bit of first byte is always 0.

I saw this exp. on geeksforgeeks.com, so I want to ask that whether a source address has to be unicast or not. I understand that a source address is an individual address but what about broadcasting? Even if it has an individual MAC address, it is not unicasting. As a 2nd question, why is the least significant bit of first byte is always 0 and what does it have to do with source address being always an individual address? Thanks.

Comment: "_I want to ask that whether a source address has to be unicast or not._" Yes, of course a source MAC address needs to be a unicast MAC address. That is exactly what The quote above means. The I/G flag must be clear, meaning an individual (unicast) MAC address, not a group (multicast/broadcast) address. The first octet must be an even number. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809679/3745413) about the MAC address flags.

Comment: "_but what about broadcasting? Even if it has an individual MAC address, it is not unicasting._" The source MAC address will still be a unicast MAC address; it is the destination MAC address that will be a group address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libvirtError: XML error: expected unicast mac address, found multicast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808705/libvirterror-xml-error-expected-unicast-mac-address-found-multicast)